# L'emploi de l'adjectif « cher, chère » sans adjectif possessif ni nom pour exprimer la familiarité au Québec : précisions ?

Tags: adjectifs, québec, registre-familier, possessif

On rencontrerait parfois au Québec un emploi (très) familier de l'adjectif *[cher, chère](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cher)* seul, au singulier, et sans adjectif possessif pour exprimer la familiarité, l'affection, à son interlocuteur, et ce serait *je crois* surtout dit par une personne plus âgée à une personne plus jeune ou à des enfants, ou employé réciproquement ou non entre deux femmes.

> Comment vas-tu, chère/cher ?
>   Cher/chère, pourrais-tu stp. me passer le beurre ?

Est-ce bien le cas, peut-on confirmer le registre (très familier ?), la géométrie et la géographie de cet emploi ?

Comment: Pas de réponse exhaustive à donner juste pour signaler que j'ai des collègues et amis (France) avec qui je travaille de façon virtuelle et qui commencent leurs messages collectifs par *chers, chères*, pour moi ça ne fait pas familier mais désuet.

Comment: @Laure Ailleurs j'avais dit _vieux_ je crois, c'est quelque chose que je suis certain de m'être fait dire bien plus que quelque chose que j'aurais dit moi-même. Mais vraiment pas au pluriel, je trouve ça inusité.